# Hyper-v does not shut down pc

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization, hyper-v

1. I log in to my Hyper-v host server
2. I open the Hyper-V manager, select my server S1 and click Connect
3. When I want to shut down server S1 or reboot server S1, I just click the start button and select shut down or restart (it's a server 2008 r2).

Now this is my problem. The Connect window turns blue (like the default background of the server) and doesn't do a thing (not even after 10minutes, I also don't see any cpu activity in the hyper-v manager).

Only when I select "Shut down" in my Hyper-v manager the server starts shutting down.

I only have this with this one server (it runs Exchange 2010 if that helps...)

In the Administrative Events from S1 I also see these warnings, but i'm not sure if they have anything to do with this problem:

```
Winlogon Event 6005: The winlogon notification subscriber <GPClient> is taking long time to handle the notification event (EndShell).

Winlogon Event 6006: The winlogon notification subscriber <GPClient> took 241 second(s) to handle the notification event (EndShell).
```

**Update:**
at logon/logoff I have 1 powershell [script](http://teusje.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/windows-server-logging-users-logon-and-logoff-via-powershell/) running that logs the user (but other server have this also..)
**Update 2:**
I logged in via RDC to the server. I logged of and the RDC screen was blue and doesn't do a thing.
When I went to the hyper-v host server and when I clicked 'Connect' I see the Ctrl+Alt+Del screen of the server.
But when I login from the hyper-v host server and I log off I see the blue background there. It's like that the window is not getting a refresh or hangs.

I hope anyone could help me with this.

Comment: Actually, I think that you've titled your question wrong.  Hyper-V does shut down your VM, as evidenced by pushing the "shut down" button in the Hyper-V manager.  What doesn't work is telling the guest OS to shut itself down, which has little to do with Hyper-V.

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with Hyper-v or not, I thought that it had something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
First make sure you do gpupdate
Next use the command: gpresult /z>policy.txt

If you have scripts running at logon or logoff check the policies via gpedit.msc.

My problem was a policy which was not set correctly and I changed an old script to a powershell script and that runs much better now!

Update:
also make sure you didn't add any powershell scripts as regular scripts or the other way around, that would also result in a 'hang'.